# Unity StopCoroutine does not stop coroutines when there are multi-layer (or nested) "yield return"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

If I use one-layer `yield return`, `StopCoroutine()` can successfully stop my coroutine. See the code example below...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestStopcoroutine : MonoBehaviour {
  IEnumerator co = null;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    co = FunA();
    StartCoroutine(co);
  }

  private IEnumerator FunA() {
    Debug.Log("Enter FunA...");
    yield return RepeatPrint();
    Debug.Log("FunA end...");
  }

  private IEnumerator RepeatPrint() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      Debug.Log(i);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Set this function to a button on UI Canvas 
  /// </summary>
  public void OnCancelButtonClick() {
    if (co != null) {
      StopCoroutine(co);
      Debug.Log("Stop Coroutine...");
      co = null;
    }
  }
}
```

this output is...

```
// Enter FunA...
// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// Stop Coroutine...
```

However, if I add one layer (i.e.`FunB()`), `FunA()` will be stopped but the inside coroutine(`FunB()`) will not be stopped. See the example code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestStopcoroutine : MonoBehaviour {
  IEnumerator co = null;

  void Start () {
    co = FunA();
    StartCoroutine(co);
  }

  private IEnumerator FunA() {
    Debug.Log("Enter FunA...");
    yield return FunB();
    Debug.Log("FunA end...");
  }

  private IEnumerator FunB () {
    Debug.Log("Enter FunB...");
    yield return RepeatPrint();
    Debug.Log("FunB end...");
  }

  private IEnumerator RepeatPrint() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      Debug.Log(i);
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Set this function to a button on UI Canvas 
  /// </summary>
  public void OnCancelButtonClick() {
    if (co != null) {
      StopCoroutine(co);
      Debug.Log("Stop Coroutine...");
      co = null;
    }
  }
}
```

this output is...

```
// Enter FunA...
// Enter FunB...
// 0
// 1
// 2
// Stop Coroutine...
// 3
// 4
// FunB end...
```

Therefore, I am wondering why `StopCoroutine()` cannot successfully stop multi-layer `yield return` coroutine??

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Comment: my Unity version is 5.6.4p3

Comment: Ok. See my answer. As long as your second code is your actual code then your output is wrong. Something is wrong in project. See my answer for reasons why this could happen. If you have a question, leave under my answer

Answer (score 3):

For your second code, the log should indeed end at `Stop Coroutine....`.

There are three possibilities to why it is showing the current output: (Very likely in order why this is happening)

**1**. You are setting  `Time.timeScale` to `0`. Search in your whole project and make sure that you're not doing this:  `Time.timeScale = 0;`. This can pause or upause a coroutine function that's waiting with `WaitForSeconds`. If you did, temporary remove or comment it out and see if it's the issue.

**2**. Your project is corrupted and there is now a bug in it. Sometimes, a bug can randomly happen in a Unity project and the only way to fix that is to create a new project and manually move the resources from the old project to the new one.

Create a new project and test your modified code below.

**3**. A bug with Unity itself. Since you're using *Unity 5.6.4p3*, there is chance this is bug with Unity. If doing what's in **#1** and **#2** did not solve your issue then simply update Unity to the latest version (Unity 2018.xxx). This is more likely to fix your issue and don't forget to test with a new project instead of importing the old one.

Use the modified code from your question below to test **#2** and **#3**. It uses the `Invoke` function to stop the coroutine after **one** second.

```
IEnumerator co = null;

void Start()
{
    co = FunA();
    Invoke("OnCancelButtonClick", 1f);
    StartCoroutine(co);
}

private IEnumerator FunA()
{
    Debug.Log("Enter FunA...");
    yield return FunB();
    Debug.Log("FunA end...");
}

private IEnumerator FunB()
{
    Debug.Log("Enter FunB...");
    yield return RepeatPrint();
    Debug.Log("FunB end...");
}

private IEnumerator RepeatPrint()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(i);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Set this function to a button on UI Canvas 
/// </summary>
public void OnCancelButtonClick()
{
    if (co != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(co);
        Debug.Log("Stop Coroutine...");
        co = null;
    }
}
```

The expected output:

```
Enter FunA...

Enter FunB...

0

Stop Coroutine...
```

---

To address [KYL3R's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553311/3785314) statement in his answer that stopping the main Coroutine won't affect any other coroutine, that has already been started. This is partially true but totally depends on how and where the coroutine was started.

**There are two ways to start a coroutine function**:

**1**. Start a coroutine with the `StartCoroutine` function from any function like a function with a `void` return type.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(RepeatPrint());
}
```

or

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(RepeatPrint());
}
```

**2**. Start a coroutine function **without** the `StartCoroutine` function by yielding the coroutine function you want to start. This must be done inside a coroutine function or a function with `IEnumerator` return type. It can't be done in a normal function like a `void` function.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return RepeatPrint();
}
```

When you start a coroutine with `StartCoroutine` then start children coroutines after with `StartCoroutine` but then killed the parent coroutine, the children coroutine functions will and should **continue** to run untouched.

Now, when you start a coroutine with `StartCoroutine` then start children coroutines after with `yield return YourCoroutine()` **without** using the `StartCoroutine` function but then killed the parent coroutine, the children coroutine functions will and should **terminate or stop** immediately so as the parent one.

*It's not surprising that most Unity users don't know because it is not documented but it's something that's very important to know when using coroutine in Unity.*

Comment: I tested your code on both Unity 2017 and Unity 2018 versions. It works as my expectation on the 2018 version, but it doesn't on the 2017 version. Therefore, according to your guess #3, this bug belongs to Unity itself, and Unity fixes it after Unity 2018 version.

Comment: One more finding: If I add a layer (i.e. `FunC()` after `FunB()` and before `RepeatPrint()`), this coroutine will not be stopped as well on the 2018 version

Comment: I suspect that was a bug *"If I add a layer (i.e. FunC() after FunB() and before RepeatPrint()), this coroutine will not be stopped as well on the 2018 version"* Can you provide a n example code for this on "pastebin.com" then link it here? I will take a look and tell you what's wrong

Comment: Hi @Programmer, the example code is here [link](https://pastebin.com/QHM5enrg). I tested this code on Unity 2018.2.1f1 version.

Comment: @Programmer `yield return myFunction` inside a Coroutine is not starting a coroutine it's just calling myFunction as if you just put myFunction's code inside your coroutine, without calling `StartCoroutine` you're not starting a new coroutine but just calling a function, so @KYL3R is true

Answer (score -1):

Coroutines run independent from each other. So stopping the main Coroutine won't affect any other, that has already been started.

It seems you have 2 options:

A: [Stop the nested Coroutine from inside the first level](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html)

- Store a Reference to `RepeatPrint` and use **that** to stop it using StopCoroutine.

edit: actually "from inside the first level" is not necessary, just use the correct Reference.

B: [Stop ALL Coroutines in your MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopAllCoroutines.html)

- May work if you have no other Coroutines running

Comment: *"So stopping the main Coroutine won't affect any other, that has already been started."* This is not quite true.  StopCoroutine should kill all coroutines running inside it.

Comment: The docs don't say anything about it. I found a Forum entry that states they are [independent](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1182632/problem-with-stopping-nested-coroutines-control-ne.html) - if you have any source that clarifies stopping Behaviour on nested coroutines, please link it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not  documented but what you said is not entirely true. Some parts are true some others are not. I want to leave an answer to explain why but need to know OP's Unity version before doing so

Comment: Hi @Programmer, my Unity version is 5.6.4p3